# jQuery hide div popup for lifetime browser cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I currently use the following code to hide a specific element on my page after 5 seconds. But when refreshing the page, the element popups again.

How can I extend my code, so that it will be hidden for lifetime (or when browser cache cleared)

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
  $('#data-popup-box-container').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);   
</script>
```

Comment: You can use the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save if the popup should be displayed - and only display it when the local sotrage variable is not set.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me some help to achieve this with code?

Comment: @HenkZ Please read my answer. :)

Comment: Exactly like @KrunalPanchal answer. Just keep in mind the usability, I might not see it in the first five seconds when my connection is slow..

Comment: @inetphantom You are right! I have edited my answer now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To hide an Element for Lifetime can be achieved using the below approach**

1. When you are hiding the popup, Set a Localstorage key
2. On document ready check if Localstorage key exists, Remove element directly

**Example code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Your existing code + store entry in LocalStorage */
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#data-popup-box-container').fadeOut('fast');

        // Add entry in localstorage that Popup displayed once :)
        localStorage.setItem("popupDisplayed", "yes");
    }, 5000);   

    /* On reload check if localstorage value is yes :) */
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var popupDisplayed = localStorage.getItem("popupDisplayed");
        /* If local storage value is yes - remove element directly from dom */
        if(popupDisplayed && popupDisplayed == 'yes') {
           $('#data-popup-box-container').remove();
        }
    });

</script>
```

**UPDATE::**

As per @inetphantom suggested in his comment, If popup will never be displayed if the connection is slow. So, Your code to hide popup should be

```
     /* Check if all resource are loaded */
     $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('#data-popup-box-container').fadeOut('fast');

           // Add entry in localstorage that Popup displayed once :)
           localStorage.setItem("popupDisplayed", "yes");
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Read more on Window load [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Answer (score -1):

Using cookie and jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(!$.cookie("hide-popup-box-containe") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#data-popup-box-container').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000); 
    $.cookie("hide-popup-box-containe",true);
  } else $('#data-popup-box-container').fadeOut('fast');
</script>
```

Comment: Cookies are good, but If you don't need it, LocalStorage should be used now.